# Django - IntegrityError: duplicate key value

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using `Django` and `PostgreSQL` and i had to make some modification to my database like deleting and moving tables around.

Now when i try to edit the records in those tables using the admin panel of `Django`, i get `Server 500 Error` with the following message:

> IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "database_pkey" DETAIL: Key(id)=(17523) already exists.

How can i fix this?

EDIT:

I get this error for literally every field in every table i try to edit, so the `database_pkey` varies depends on the field.

Comment: Can you show some code of what are you actually doing?

Comment: Specifically can you post your models.py files, admin.py, and migrations

Comment: I think you are making an INSERT not an UPDATE on the row.
Try something like this ModelClass.objects.filter(name='bar').update(name="foo")

Comment: I'm using the admin panel, not SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were making the same mistake I was in your models.

I was overriding one of the model methods, `save()` and calling the super method `super().save(...)` but my arguments were `super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)` which is wrong. It should be `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`. Django let me get away with this error before. I don't know if it was just because I was only adding objects before and not editing them or if it started after running some migrations.